# DateTimeParseException: fails on one host, works on another, same JDK

Tags: java, date

I'm absolutely baffled. I'm on OpenJdk 11.0.3 both locally and up on my production host. One parses a date and one doesn't. Any ideas on what could be causing the difference?

Edit: hacky work around noted at the end

Same JDK:

```
kesselc:~/openjdk-11.0.3+7/bin$ ./java -version
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+7, mixed mode)

prodhost: # java -version
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Different results:

```
kesselc:$ ~/openjdk-11.0.3+7/bin/java DateTest
2019-07-10T09:48-06:00[America/Denver]

prodhost: # java DateTest
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '948 AM MDT Wed Jul 10 2019' could not be parsed: null
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2017)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:598)
    at DateTest.main(DateTest.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$PrefixTree.prefixLength(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4527)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$PrefixTree.add0(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4396)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$PrefixTree.add(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4391)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$ZoneTextPrinterParser.getTree(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4138)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$ZoneIdPrinterParser.parse(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4249)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.parse(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2370)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseUnresolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2107)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2036)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    ... 2 more
```

Here's the simple test class I'm running on both:

```
public class DateTest {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter hhmm_a_zzz_EEE_MMM_dd_yyyy = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("hmm a zzz EEE MMM d yyyy")
            .toFormatter();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("948 AM MDT Wed Jul 10 2019", hhmm_a_zzz_EEE_MMM_dd_yyyy));
    }
}
```

Edit: My solution, of a sort. In this case, I'm parsing NOAA forecasts that are specifically US-centric. So, I hacked my own equivalent of ZoneId.of("MDT") to map to an offset for the 17 time zones noted here: https://www.timetemperature.com/abbreviations/united_states_time_zone_abbreviations.shtml

I feel vaguely dirty and ashamed, but this particular date parser is specific to this particular source, so I'll call it good enough.

I still don't know why the 2 systems behaved differently, but now the problem is irrelevant.

Here's the `System.getProperties` dump on the two systems.

Good (`kesselc`):

> {sun.desktop=gnome, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit, java.specification.version=11, sun.cpu.isalist=, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, java.class.path=., java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.arch.data.model=64, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, user.timezone=, os.name=Linux, java.vm.specification.version=11, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, user.country=US, sun.boot.library.path=/home/kesselc/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.2-open/lib, sun.java.command=DateTest, jdk.debug=release, sun.cpu.endian=little, user.home=/home/kesselc, user.language=en, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.version.date=2019-01-15, java.home=/home/kesselc/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.2-open, file.separator=/, java.vm.compressedOopsMode=Zero based, line.separator=
>   , java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, java.runtime.version=11.0.2+9, user.name=kesselc, path.separator=:, os.version=4.4.0-154-generic, java.runtime.name=OpenJDK Runtime Environment, file.encoding=UTF-8, java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, java.vendor.version=18.9, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/, java.io.tmpdir=/tmp, java.version=11.0.2, user.dir=/home/kesselc/Projects/flex/weather/out/production/classes, os.arch=amd64, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob, sun.os.patch.level=unknown, java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vm.info=mixed mode, java.vm.version=11.0.2+9, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, java.class.version=55.0}

Failing (`prodhost`):

> {awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit, java.specification.version=11, sun.cpu.isalist=, sun.jnu.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968, java.class.path=., java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.arch.data.model=64, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, user.timezone=, os.name=Linux, java.vm.specification.version=11, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, user.country=US, sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib, sun.java.command=DateTest, jdk.debug=release, sun.cpu.endian=little, user.home=/root, user.language=en, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.version.date=2019-04-16, java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64, file.separator=/, java.vm.compressedOopsMode=32-bit, line.separator=
>   , java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, java.runtime.version=11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, user.name=root, path.separator=:, os.version=4.4.0-1079-aws, java.runtime.name=OpenJDK Runtime Environment, file.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968, java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/, java.io.tmpdir=/tmp, java.version=11.0.3, user.dir=/opt/ct/deploy, os.arch=amd64, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob, sun.os.patch.level=unknown, java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vm.info=mixed mode, sharing, java.vm.version=11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, java.class.version=55.0}

Comment: Good question, my mind went there too :). No, different time zones (me: PDT, prod: UTC), but I wouldn't think that should matter since it has a time zone field in the date to parse.

Comment: Could it be the locale getting in the way?

Comment: Tell us more about your two environments.

Comment: By the way, this is a *terrible* format for a date-time string. `MDT` is not a [real time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). If the intention was for the zone used by the middle part of North America, a real time zone would be `America/Denver` or  `America/Edmonton`. If possible, educate the publisher of this data about [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: Oh, trust me, I *know* it's terrible. If you could convince NOAA to abandon it in their forecasts, that'd be great. I update the question to indicate my hacky workaround.

Comment: If you give me a link to the data source, I'll will try to [contact NOAA](https://www.noaa.gov/contact-us).

Comment: All the stuff under here: https://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/forecasts/zone. I'd be shocked if they changed it because then they risk breaking someone else.

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce your exact stacktrace on Java 9.0.4. However I believe that a locale problem is a good guess. `AM`, `MDT`, `Wed`and `Jul` are all language specific and can be parsed in an English-speaking locale and generally not elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I have been looking around in the source code of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, and I’m far from sure, but it seems to me that a possible reason for your `NullPointerException` is a null time zone abbreviation in some locale data. This could cause `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.ZoneTextPrinterParser.getTree()` to pass a null to `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.PrefixTree.add()`, which in turn doesn’t expect a null. If so, the different behaviour could be caused by a combination of different time zone and different locale. Note that time zone and locale are independent.

Edit: The questioner has reported that my suggestion doesn’t fix this particular issue. I am letting it stand because I think that the possibility of specifying preferred time zones for parsing a time zone abbreviation may be helpful for several others.

I have not reproduced your exception, so cannot give a sure way to fix, but I would like to suggest that you try:

```
    Set<ZoneId> preferredZones = Set.of(ZoneId.of("America/Goose_Bay"),
            ZoneId.of("America/Moncton"), ZoneId.of("America/New_York"),
            ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"), ZoneId.of("America/Denver"),
            ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"), ZoneId.of("America/Anchorage"),
            ZoneId.of("Pacific/Honolulu"), ZoneId.of("America/Adak"),
            ZoneId.of("Pacific/Pago_Pago"), ZoneId.of("Pacific/Guam"));
    DateTimeFormatter hhmm_a_zzz_EEE_MMM_dd_yyyy = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("hmm a ")
            .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, preferredZones)
            .appendPattern(" EEE MMM d yyyy")
            .toFormatter(Locale.US);
```

The preferred zones have been chosen to match the 17 abbreviations you link to:

```
AST        America/Goose_Bay, America/Moncton
EST EDT    America/New_York
CST CDT    America/Chicago
MST MDT    America/Denver
PST PDT    America/Los_Angeles
AKST AKDT  America/Anchorage
HST        Pacific/Honolulu
HAST HADT  America/Adak
SST SDT    Pacific/Pago_Pago
CHST       Pacific/Guam
```

You may want to check whether I have got my mappings right.

In addition, as others have already suggested, I have specified `Locale.US` for the formatter.

Comment: I appreciate all the work you went to, but it still runs into the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out and at least satisfying some of my curiosity. I'm glad you've found something that works for this special situation.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, this is mysterious. That `null` as part of the attempt to generate an error seems strange. I cannot replicate your problem, having tried 2 environments with Java 8 & 12.

I have a few suggestions:

- Always specify a `Locale` when parsing text such as name-of-day or name-of-month.
- In a separate method, simplify your code to the absolute minimum to be sure of no side-effects.
- Dump info about your JVM environment with a call to `System.getProperties()`.

Code:

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println ( "Hello World!" );
        App app = new App ();
        app.doIt ();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {


        DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder =
                new DateTimeFormatterBuilder ()
                        .parseCaseInsensitive ()
                        .appendPattern ( "hmm a zzz EEE MMM d yyyy" );

        Locale locale = Locale.US;
        DateTimeFormatter f = builder.toFormatter ( locale );

        String input = "948 AM MDT Wed Jul 10 2019";
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , f );

        System.out.println ( "zdt.toString() = " + zdt );

        System.out.println ( System.getProperties () );

    }
}
```

I ran this successfully on:

- My own Mac Mini (2018) with macOS Mojave 10.14.5 using Java 12.0.1+12 from AdoptOpenJDK with HotSpot.
- IdeOne.com running java.version=1.8.0_112 from Oracle JDK with HotSpot. See this [code run live](https://ideone.com/nOmhJY).
- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with OpenJDK 11.0.3+7 from AdoptOpenJDK.net (running in Parallels virtual machine on a Mac).
- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with Oracle JDK 11.0.3+12 from [the Oracle site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html).

Same result on all of them.

> zdt.toString() = 2019-07-10T09:48-06:00[America/Denver]

### System properties

Mac

> {awt.toolkit=sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit, java.specification.version=12, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, java.class.path=/Users/basilbourque/IdeaProjects/Demo/target/classes:/Users/basilbourque/.m2/repository/org/threeten/threeten-extra/1.5.0/threeten-extra-1.5.0.jar, java.vm.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK, sun.arch.data.model=64, java.vendor.url=https://adoptopenjdk.net/, java.vm.specification.version=12, os.name=Mac OS X, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, user.country=US, sun.boot.library.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/lib, sun.java.command=work.basil.example.App, http.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, jdk.debug=release, sun.cpu.endian=little, user.home=/Users/basilbourque, user.language=en, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.version.date=2019-04-16, java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home, file.separator=/, java.vm.compressedOopsMode=Zero based, line.separator=
>   , java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, ftp.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, java.runtime.version=12.0.1+12, user.name=basilbourque, path.separator=:, os.version=10.14.5, java.runtime.name=OpenJDK Runtime Environment, file.encoding=UTF-8, java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, java.vendor.version=AdoptOpenJDK, java.vendor.url.bug=https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues, java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/qk/grjjffnj7ml_r54rrb1c2pbw0000gn/T/, java.version=12.0.1, user.dir=/Users/basilbourque/IdeaProjects/Demo, os.arch=x86_64, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, java.library.path=/Users/basilbourque/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:., java.vm.info=mixed mode, sharing, java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK, java.vm.version=12.0.1+12, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig, socksNonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, java.class.version=56.0}

IdeOne.com

> {java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.boot.library.path=/opt/jdk/jre/lib/amd64, java.vm.version=25.112-b15, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, path.separator=:, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, user.country=US, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, sun.os.patch.level=unknown, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, user.dir=/home/uXdFYs, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_112-b15, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment, java.endorsed.dirs=/opt/jdk/jre/lib/endorsed, os.arch=amd64, java.io.tmpdir=/tmp, line.separator=
>   , java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, os.name=Linux, sun.jnu.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968, java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=52.0, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, os.version=3.16.0-4-amd64, user.home=?, user.timezone=, java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob, file.encoding=UTF-8, java.specification.version=1.8, java.class.path=tested.zip, user.name=?, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, sun.java.command=tested.zip, java.home=/opt/jdk/jre, sun.arch.data.model=64, user.language=en, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit, java.vm.info=mixed mode, java.version=1.8.0_112, java.ext.dirs=/opt/jdk/lib, sun.boot.class.path=/opt/jdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/opt/jdk/jre/classes, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, file.separator=/, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.cpu.isalist=}

Comment: I added the System.getProperties() dumps to my original post if you'd like to look. A quick eyeballing didn't show anything obvious to me except maybe encoding (and I ran it on 11.0.2 this time locally instead of 11.0.3, but I don't think that matters).

Comment: @ChrisKessel FYI, I ran a 3rd scenario, closer to your `prodhost`: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Succeeded like my two other scenarios. Perhaps you can copy the entire class file I posted in my Answer, and run on your `prodhost`. You need not even compile with Java 11, just run `java App.java` to auto-compile-and-execute.

Comment: I cut/paste your program and ran it, same result. 
# java App.java
Hello World!
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '948 AM MDT Wed Jul 10 2019' could not be parsed: null

Comment: @ChrisKessel This has really been bugging me. The only thing I noted different in your Java properties dump is (a) an ASCII file encoding, and (b) Oracle JDK rather than OpenJDK. The file encoding is just a default I believe, so it should not matter. The Oracle JDK should not matter as it is converging with OpenJDK. But what the heck, maybe I should try that. So I tried yet another virtual machine on my Mac today. No problem, my example code ran. But another difference arose: I noticed my Ubuntu auto-updated to a `18.0.2` rather then .1, and Oracle JDK 11.0.3 is now at `+12` rather than `+7`.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue before, what worked for me was changing `.toFormatter()` to `.toFormatter(Locale.US)`. I am not sure what causes this issue, it must be something with the timezones of the machines. See if this works for you.

Comment: It was a good idea, but no luck, same problem. ZoneId.SHORT_IDS says the old 3 letter format isn't maintained, and for good reason, so I'm hacking a lookup for the offset myself. I'm still baffled as to why things run differently on the two systems, but I'm going just avoid that problem completely with my own hack lookup.

Comment: @ChrisKessel That is reallly strange, let me know if you find an answer.

Comment: Giving it a +1...didn't solve my problem, but it put me on the right path (US-centric zone parsing) so I wanted to reward the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is finally a know problem, solved in Fedora, not yet in Redhat:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1837376
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1838229.

The problem is a buggy /usr/share/javazi-1.8/tzdb.dat.

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS, only the packaged jvm 11 and 14 from the distribution fails.
They are identified as:

```
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.7+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.7+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

or:

```
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 20.3 (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 20.3 (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Downloaded from AdoptOpenJDK, everything is fine:

```
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

or

```
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10, mixed mode)
```

I also have almost all JVM Since 1.8 on my mac. All of them are fine.

The format tested is:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

(edit)
The code is close to the shown example:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateTest {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(dtf.parse("Jul 15 11:20:01 CEST"));
    }
}
```

And a stack with JVM 14:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-14/bin/java -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -cp . DateTest 2>&1 | sort -u | less
        ... 1 more
        at DateTest.main(DateTest.java:9)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2021)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1878)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1882)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2040)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseUnresolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2111)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.parse(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2372)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$PrefixTree.add(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4402)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$PrefixTree.add0(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4407)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$PrefixTree.prefixLength(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4538)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$ZoneIdPrinterParser.parse(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4260)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$ZoneTextPrinterParser.getTree(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4149)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "k" is null
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jul 15 11:20:01 CEST' could not be parsed: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "k" is null
```

Comment: Can you post all of your test code, and the full error? May help anyone who cares to dig into this.