# Java OffsetDateTime cannot be parsed

Tags: java, java-time, date-parsing, datetime-parsing, offsetdatetime

I want to parse the following String into an `OffsetDateTime`:

```java
OffsetDateTime test = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00");
```

However, this results in an exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00' could not be parsed: null
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2017) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402) ~[na:na]
```

I have seen answers online where this worked right away and I have tried creating custom formatters, but these return the same error message:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ");
OffsetDateTime test = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00", formatter);
```

I am using Java 11.0.17 on Windows.

Update: It works on colleagues machine, but not mine. It also does not work when I select a different Java version in IntelliJ.

Here is the complete Stacktrace (I added it somewhere randomly in the existing project as the quickest way to test it). The stack trace is from Java 19 where a bit more information is given.

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00' could not be parsed: Cannot invoke "java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor.isSupported(java.time.temporal.TemporalField)" because "target" is null
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2077) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:2012) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:404) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:389) ~[na:na]
    at com.syngenio.fints.FintsServer.process(FintsServer.java:22) ~[main/:na]
    at com.syngenio.fis.controller.FintsController.fints(FintsController.java:24) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:201) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at com.syngenio.fis.integration.tests.ExemptionDateTest.testExemptionDate(ExemptionDateTest.java:53) ~[test/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor.isSupported(java.time.temporal.TemporalField)" because "target" is null
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.crossCheck(Parsed.java:707) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.crossCheck(Parsed.java:698) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.resolve(Parsed.java:267) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeParseContext.toResolved(DateTimeParseContext.java:331) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2112) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:2008) ~[na:na]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (Java (Temurin) 11.0.17 Windows 11).

Comment: @Fenio The error reports `Text '2021-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00' could not be parsed`, which means the input was not null. I'd sooner guess there might be some non-printable character in there or something (though if I try that, I get a different error).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OffsetDateTime parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048032/offsetdatetime-parsing)

Comment: @f1sh How would that answer the question? The code as given in this question is correct and works fine on my machine.

Comment: Related: [DateTimeParseException: fails on one host, works on another, same JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56976974/datetimeparseexception-fails-on-one-host-works-on-another-same-jdk) (no resolution though), I wonder if it is somehow related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8226704, but that bug is a lot older than Java 11.0.17 and is marked as resolved. However, this might suggest that the problem might be related to Locale settings on your machine.

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(java.util.Locale.getDefault())` on your machine? What is the configured region in your windows region settings, (e.g. the "Regional format")

Comment: That’s weird alright. I’d get hold of the source code of the JDK and debug through it. Unfortunately the line numbers of your Java 19 stack trace do not match the Java 18 source code I have at hand.

Comment: Likely diagnosis from looking through the JDK source on GitHub: `java.time.format.Parsed.crossCheck()` line 698: `crossCheck(date.atTime(time));`. `atTme()` returns `null` (one may research why), which causes a `NullPointerException` in `crossCheck(TemporalAccessor)` line 707: `if (target.isSupported(field)) {`. The NPE is caught in `DateTimeFormatter.parse(CharSequence, TemporalQuery)` line 2011: `} catch (RuntimeException ex) {`, from where `createError()` is called. If you can reproduce it in a tiny example with no suspicious circumstances, I think you can report it into the JDK bug system.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the locale is "de_DE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem:

The call was made inside an integration test where `LocalDateTime::now` was mocked. By default, `MockedStatic` does *not* keep the other methods, so things like `LocalDateTime::of` just return `null` (very unintuitive design decision imo). Behind the scenes, the parser obviously calls a method by `LocalDateTime`, resulting in this weird error. Changing `Mockito.mockStatic(LocalDateTime.class)` to `Mockito.mockStatic(LocalDateTime.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)` fixed the problem.